# JQuery swap 4 divs

Tags: jquery

I have 4 divs, 3 of them are thumbs and a big size one div. All i want is to click on small div and swap content with the big div.
I have an html code:

```
<div id='t1'>CONTENT 1</div>
<div id='t2'>CONTENT 2</div>
<div id='t3'>CONTENT 3</div>
<div id='big'>CONTENT DEFAULT</div>
```

For example if i click on div id=t1 the content of div t1 will be CONTENT DEFAULT and the

content of the div id=big will be CONTENT 1

Comment: can you show the html? what have you tryed in jquery too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jQuery should work, using the swap / temp pattern:

```
$('div[id^=t]').on('click', function() {
   var tmp = $('#big').html();
   $('#big').html($(this).html());
   $(this).html(tmp);
});​
```

*Edit* - Updated for your exact html

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnd3M/5/)

Comment: Thank you, this is it. The class of the divs did the difference

Comment: @MrM - I've updated to match your original html. `div[id^=t]` will bind the handler to any div 'starting with id' = 't'

Comment: nice one tx , but the one with the class was ok also